# C++ pattern: 1x base class + Nx derived classes BUT with a _last resort_ derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement a logger with 3 levels of information: general (date/time), context, message

To reach this goal I'm trying to implemnet the following pattern:

1. Logger class (non relevant here)
2. Context class

   - Base class `LoggerContext`, this has the functionality of generating the general level infos
   - Derived class, which add the context specific infos (specific for a part of the application)

The interesting part starts as I try to have a *none* context. That is, if the Logger is called without context, then a singleton `LoggerContextNone` should be used.

Here my code, that regardless of how I turn it, does not compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

enum class LoggerArea {
        LOGGER_NONE, LOGGER_DOWNLOAD, LOGGER_COMPUTE,
};

class ELoggerContext: std::runtime_error {
        using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class LoggerContextNone; // forward declaration, only needed for 
                         // the commented version of the code

class LoggerContext {
protected:
        LoggerArea mLA;
public:
        LoggerContext(LoggerArea la);
        virtual ~LoggerContext() = 0;
        /*
        static LoggerContext& getEmptyContext() {
                static LoggerContextNone loggerContextNone = { LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE };
                return loggerContextNone;
        }
        */
        std::string getGeneral();
        virtual std::string getContext() = 0; // pure virtual
};

string LoggerContext::getGeneral() {
        return "general informations";
}
LoggerContext::LoggerContext(LoggerArea la) :
                mLA(la) {
  if (la == LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE) {
        throw ELoggerContext("LOGGER_NONE cannot be instantiated");
  }
}

class LoggerContextNone : LoggerContext {
private:
        LoggerContextNone() {
                mLA = LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE;
        }
public:
        virtual ~LoggerContextNone() override {

        }
        virtual std::string getContext() override {
                return " ";
        }
        static LoggerContextNone& getInstance() {
                static LoggerContextNone instance {};
                return instance;
        }
};

int main() {
  // this should not be compilable:
  LoggerContextNone n{LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE};
  // this should at least throw an error at run time:
  LoggerContext n{LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE};
  return 0;
}
```

Goals:

- `LoggerContextNone` should derive from `LoggerContext`, because we need `getGeneral()`
- `LoggerContextNone` should not be instantiable outside getInstance (singleton)
- the base class should have no empty constructor, BUT the derived class should have one
- `LoggerContextNone` should not call the super constructor, otherwise it would throw an error `ELoggerContext`
- any derived class from `LoggerContext` should not be able to override `getGeneral()`

Is it actually possible to achieve this in C++? I'm looking for a clean solution (no factory, ...)

The compiler's error are:

```
19_virtual_class.cpp: In constructor ‘LoggerContextNone::LoggerContextNone()’:
19_virtual_class.cpp:45:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘LoggerContext::LoggerContext()’
  LoggerContextNone() {
                      ^
[...]
19_virtual_class.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
19_virtual_class.cpp:62:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘LoggerContextNone::LoggerContextNone(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   LoggerContextNone n{LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE};
                                              ^
```

Final note: This pattern seems me conceptually simple: Many class's derived from a base class with additionally a default class.

**EDIT:**

If I adjust the code as by @Angew :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

enum class LoggerArea {
        LOGGER_NONE, LOGGER_DOWNLOAD, LOGGER_COMPUTE,
};

class ELoggerContext: std::runtime_error {
        using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class LoggerContextNone;

class LoggerContext {
protected:
        LoggerArea mLA;

        class LoggerContextNone_AccessToken
        {
                friend LoggerContextNone;
                LoggerContextNone_AccessToken() {}
        };
        explicit LoggerContext(LoggerContextNone_AccessToken) : mLA(LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE) {}
public:
        LoggerContext(LoggerArea la);
        virtual ~LoggerContext() = 0;
        std::string getGeneral();
        virtual std::string getContext() = 0;
};

string LoggerContext::getGeneral() {
        string s = "general informations:";
        if (mLA==LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE) { s += "LOGGER_NONE"; }
        else if (mLA==LoggerArea::LOGGER_DOWNLOAD) { s += "LOGGER_DOWNLOAD"; }
        else if (mLA==LoggerArea::LOGGER_COMPUTE) { s += "LOGGER_COMPUTE"; }
        else { s += "??????????"; }

        return s;
}
LoggerContext::LoggerContext(LoggerArea la) :
                mLA(la) {
  if (la == LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE) {
        throw ELoggerContext("LOGGER_NONE cannot be instantiated");
  }
}

class LoggerContextNone : LoggerContext {
private:
        LoggerContextNone(): LoggerContext(LoggerContextNone_AccessToken()) {}
public:
        virtual ~LoggerContextNone() override {

        }
        virtual std::string getContext() override {
                return " ";
        }
        static LoggerContextNone& getInstance() {
                static LoggerContextNone instance {};
                return instance;
        }
};

class LoggerContextDerived : LoggerContext {
public:
        virtual std::string getContext() override {
                return "derived context";
        }
};

int main() {
  LoggerContextDerived n {LoggerArea::LOGGER_DOWNLOAD};

  // cout << "General : " << n.getGeneral() << endl;
  // cout << "Context : " << n.getContext() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I cannot instantiate a derived class. `g++` says:

```
9_virtual_class.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
19_virtual_class.cpp:78:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘LoggerContextDerived::LoggerContextDerived(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   LoggerContextDerived n {LoggerArea::LOGGER_DOWNLOAD};
                                                      ^
```

And it suggest me to use the copy constructor or the move constructor.
That means to me that the constructor

```
LoggerContext(LoggerArea la);
```

is not visible in the derived class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want, but not quite in the way you've tried. The problematic requirement is this one:

> `LoggerContextNone` should not call the super constructor, otherwise it would throw an error `ELoggerContext`

A derived class will **always** call a constructor of the base class. In C++, you cannot legally have a valid object of a class type without having run its constructor.

However, note that it will call *a* constructor of the base, meaning it can call an arbitrary one (derived class decides). So you could give the base class a constructor specifically intended for use by `LoggerContextNone`, something like this:

```
class LoggerContext {
protected:
        LoggerArea mLA;
        LoggerContext() : mLA(LOGGER_NONE) {}
public:
        LoggerContext(LoggerArea la);
        virtual ~LoggerContext() = 0;
        /*
        static LoggerContext& getEmptyContext() {
                static LoggerContextNone loggerContextNone = { LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE };
                return loggerContextNone;
        }
        */
        std::string getGeneral();
        virtual std::string getContext() = 0; // pure virtual
};
```

This will achieve what you want, but it will allow all classes derived from `LoggerContext` to call that default constructor, should they choose to do so. If you want to avoid that and *only* make that constructor available to `LoggerContextNone`, you can use friendship tricks and tag dispatch to do so:

```
class LoggerContext
{
protected:
  class LoggerContextNone_AccessToken
  {
    friend LoggerContextNone;
    LoggerContextNone_AccessToken() {}
  };

  explicit LoggerContext(LoggerContextNone_AccessToken) : mLA(LOGGER_NONE) {}
protected:
  // ... the rest as before
};

LoggerContextNone::LoggerContextNone() : LoggerContext(LoggerContextNone_AccessToken())
{}
```

This means that:

1. To call the non-throwing constructor of `LoggerContext`, you need to pass in a `LoggerContextNone_AccessToken` object.
2. `LoggerContextNone_AccessToken` has a private constructor, which means only its friends can construct it.
3. `LoggerContextNone` is the only friend of `LoggerContextNone_AccessToken`, so it is the only class capable of constructing a `LoggerContextNone_AccessToken` and therefore the only class capable of calling the non-throwing constructor of `LoggerContext`.

---

Alternatively, you could consider whether you actually need `LoggerContextNone` at all. Perhaps you could have `LoggerContext` behave as `LoggerContextNone`, and just allow derived classes to provide non-none behaviour.

Comment: thank you for your long reply, but it seams to be that something is still not working with the constructor, see my edit of the question.

Comment: @LiPo That's a rather unrelated issue. You cannot use a base-class ctor to construct a derived class in C++. If you want a single-param ctor in the derived class, you need to define such a ctor there. Or use constructor inheritance (`using LoggerContext::LoggerContext`), but that will inherit *all* constructors.

Comment: @LiPo You might want to read up more on how C++ constructors work in a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Angew is essential to make the pattern work, but there were many (and still there are some) other issues in the code.

This is best I could make out of it, it is still not working, but perhaps in the next days I get it 100%:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

enum class LoggerArea {
        LOGGER_NONE, LOGGER_DOWNLOAD, LOGGER_COMPUTE,
};

class ELoggerContext: std::runtime_error {
        using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class LoggerContextNone;

class LoggerContext {
protected:
        LoggerArea mLA;

        class LoggerContextNone_AccessToken
        {
                friend LoggerContextNone;
                LoggerContextNone_AccessToken() {}
        };
        explicit LoggerContext(LoggerContextNone_AccessToken) : mLA(LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE) {}
public:
        LoggerContext(LoggerArea la);
        virtual ~LoggerContext() {};
        std::string getGeneral();
        virtual std::string getContext() = 0;
};

string LoggerContext::getGeneral() {
        string s = "general informations:";
        if (mLA==LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE) { s += "LOGGER_NONE"; }
        else if (mLA==LoggerArea::LOGGER_DOWNLOAD) { s += "LOGGER_DOWNLOAD"; }
        else if (mLA==LoggerArea::LOGGER_COMPUTE) { s += "LOGGER_COMPUTE"; }
        else { s += "??????????"; }

        return s;
}
LoggerContext::LoggerContext(LoggerArea la) :
                mLA(la) {
  if (la == LoggerArea::LOGGER_NONE) {
        throw ELoggerContext("LOGGER_NONE cannot be instantiated");
  }
}

class LoggerContextNone : LoggerContext {
private:
        LoggerContextNone(): LoggerContext(LoggerContextNone_AccessToken()) {}
public:
        virtual ~LoggerContextNone() override {

        }
        virtual std::string getContext() override {
                return " ";
        }
        static LoggerContextNone* getInstance() {
        // this was:
        // static LoggerContextNone& getInstance() {
                static LoggerContextNone instance {};
                return &instance;
        }
};

class LoggerContextDerived : public LoggerContext {
public:
        LoggerContextDerived(LoggerArea la):LoggerContext(la) {  };
        virtual std::string getContext() override {
                return "derived context";
        }
        virtual ~LoggerContextDerived() override {

        }
};

int main() {

  // test 1: derived class
  LoggerContextDerived c1 {LoggerArea::LOGGER_DOWNLOAD};   // ok

  cout << "General : " << c1.getGeneral() << endl;         // ok
  cout << "Context : " << c1.getContext() << endl;         // ok

  LoggerContext * c2 = &c1;                                // ok

  // test 2: derived none class
  LoggerContextNone * c3 = LoggerContextNone::getInstance();   // ok
  LoggerContext * c4 = c3;                                     // g++ error:
    // error: ‘LoggerContext’ is an inaccessible base of ‘LoggerContextNone’
  LoggerContext * c5 = LoggerContextNone::getInstance();       // g++ error:
    // error: ‘LoggerContext’ is an inaccessible base of ‘LoggerContextNone’

  return 0;
}
```